# GCP BigQuery Calendar Table - Corresponding day last year

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am building a Calendar Table in Biquery. How can I get Corresponding date last year based on the calendar date considering leap year as well as I am building the calendar from 2010 to 2050

My SQL so far

```
SELECT
  date,
  FORMAT_DATE("%A", date) as day_of_week,
  EXTRACT(DAY FROM date) as the_day,
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) as the_month,
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) AS year,
  FORMAT_DATE("%b", date) as month_name,
  FORMAT_DATE("%B", date) as month_name_full,
  EXTRACT(WEEK FROM date) AS week,
 FORMAT_DATE("%d-%m-%E4Y", date) as Date_DDMMYYYY,
 FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m", date) as Date_YYYYMM,
 FORMAT_DATE("%Y-%m", date) as Date_YYYY_MM,
 FORMAT_DATE("%m-%Y", date) as Date_MM_YYYY,
 EXTRACT(month from date_add(date, interval 6 month)) as fiscal_month,
 EXTRACT(year from date_add(date, interval 6 month)) as fiscal_year,
 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date)+1 as Year_Offset_PLUS_1,
 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date)-1 as Year_Offset_MINUS_1,


 FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2010-01-01', '2050-12-31')) AS Date
ORDER BY date;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: what exactly is your definition of `Corresponding day last year`?

Comment: I am trying to compare Sales on a Particular day this year 5/3/2021 which is a Friday to corresponding Day last year. Comparing Sales for a Friday to a Friday, as you can see in the output table the corresponding Date might be different.

Comment: I would use something like this in Tableau --> DATE_ADD( ‘week’, -52, [Date Dimension] )

Comment: BigQuery has DATE_SUB and DATE_ADD so -use it then :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL 52 WEEK)
```